# Есть срез []bson.Raw, как его корректно отдать в виде json с сервера?

Tags: json, golang

Вот код со структурой ответа, paginatedData.Data является срезом []bson.Raw:

```
response := map[string]interface{}{
    "users": paginatedData.Data,
    "pagination": Pagination{
        CurrentPage: 1,
        PageCount:   int(paginatedData.Pagination.TotalPage),
        TotalCount:  int(paginatedData.Pagination.Total),
        PerPage:     perPage,
    },
}
respondWithJson(w, http.StatusOK, response)
```

Метод respondWithJson:

```
func respondWithJson(w http.ResponseWriter, code int, payload interface{}) {
    response, _ := json.Marshal(payload)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(code)
    w.Write(response)
}
```

Подскажите как правильно отдать json.А то получается вот такая каша.

[image: А то получается вот такая каша]

Comment: Всё правильно получилось. Тип `bson.Raw` - это массив байтов. `json.Marshal` кодирует байтовые массивы в base64. Если вы хотите в своём ответе увидеть структуру, то вам нужно сначала декодировать эти бинарные строки. Например, `user := map[string]interface{}{}; paginatedData.Data[i].Unmarshal(&user)` декодирует i-ю запись из `paginatedData.Data` в отображение из строки в строку.

Comment: да, спасибо, именно так мне и нужно